# c# ews find an email that only sent without saving

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

i try to find an email that only sent and not saved in the sent-folder.

```
// Send E-Mail
Guid MyUniquePropertySetId = Guid.NewGuid();

MyExtendedPropertyDefinition =
  new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MyUniquePropertySetId , "OwnMessageId", MapiPropertyType.String);

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(ExchangeService);

message.ToRecipients.AddRange(email.SendTo.GetEmailAdressRange());
message.Subject = email.Subject;
message.Body = email.Text;

email.OwnMessageId = Guid.NewGuid();

message.SetExtendedProperty(MyExtendedPropertyDefinition, email.OwnMessageId.ToString());

message.Send();

// Find E-Mail
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(MyExtendedPropertyDefinition, mail.OwnMessageId.ToString());

FindItemsResults<Item> results = ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, filter, view);

Item item = results.FirstOrDefault();
```

But the email was not found.

**Is it possible to find the email?**

I will use it, to save the sent email as eml-file at a document-management-system.

May be there is an other way to get the mime-content of the EmailMessage.

Comment: No you won't be able to find it anywhere, the message will be submitted to the Exchange Store (Message Submission Endpoint) and because the SaveToSentItems options isn't used that means a copy won't be saved in the Mailbox, its the same as if you where sending the Message via SMTP

Comment: And there are a way to save the mimeContent before send the email?

Something like that...

`message.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
email.EmlData = message.MimeContent.Content;`

Comment: If you first saved the Message as a draft that should work, it maybe the datetime and internetMessageId aren't available but give it a try. The mimeContent wouldn't include your custom property